# MongoDB custom field query

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

I am not sure this is a duplicated question or not (I don't think so) but its very interesting question for me:

In SQL we can create custom field and put it in the result:

```
SELECT *.p, totalOrder=(SELECT sum(price) from orders where id=p.id)
```

FROM products p;

so the result is a list of products with totalSales value.

What is best approach in NoSQL(MongoDB), 
I am sure we should have two types of socuments(products and orders) so I know we don't have Join but the question is do we have custom field assignment in finding queries?

Answer (score 1):

When you use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), you have the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operation which is exactly that. It is used to rename fields or derive field values through [some simple operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#expression-operators). But as usual with MongoDB, you can not get any data from another collection.

When you need to do something which is too complex to express with aggregation, you can use [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) and build your output-documents with Javascript. But again, no breaking out of the collection.